# Printing hex/binary strings to a file in nodejs

Tags: node.js, encryption, buffer, file-writing

I'm trying to do something seemingly simple:

```
var token = crypto.randomBytes(32);
var wstream = fs.createWriteStream('output.hex');
wstream.write(token);
wstream.end();
```

The `output.hex` file is empty after this code is run. `token` is never modified during the code either.

In the same vein, I try this:

```
// encrypts a message
var token = crypto.randomBytes(32);
var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-cbc', token);
var enc_msg = cipher.update(msg, 'binary', 'binary');
enc_msg += cipher.final('binary');

// print it
console.log(enc_msg);  // prints Øôâ¨7"ªðqâ~è (binary data - good)

// check the type
console.log(type of enc_msg); // prints 'string'

// write it to a file (fails)
var wstream = fs.createWriteStream('output.hex');
wstream.write(enc_msg);
wstream.end();
```

What am I missing here? The file is always completely empty.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the issue was.

the `wstream.write()` function is asynchronous (it wasn't obvious to me because I wasn't providing a callback). So as my script was trying to write to the file, it got to my `process.exit(0)` command (not in the original question) and terminated the script before actually writing.

Removing the forced exit and letting the script terminate when it's ready worked like a charm.